# Full screen site in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I've been working on a website design for a chat site, but every attempt I make to get it right has failed so far. I have tried to do it with tables, it always failed in one browser (Mostly IE tho), divs, and a lot more.

The website has to be fullscreen, with a min-width of 900 and a min-height:500px so it won't get any smaller. I want to do this without any javascript (I have made it in JS, but this needs to be done without it :< )

Here is a picture of what it should look like.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdppC.jpg]

I hope this is possible in pure CSS/HTML

Thanks in advance

EDIT

I got it working in Firefox + Chrome, but IE decides to not follow any rule...

```
<html>
 <head>
 <style type="text/css">
  body{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
   outline: 0;
   font-size: 100%;
   vertical-align: baseline;
  }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
  <div style="position: relative; height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: gray; min-width: 900px; min-height: 500px;">
   <div style="position: absolute; height: 30px;left:0px; right: 300px ; background-color: yellow; bottom: 0;">
    Input
   </div>

   <div style="position: absolute; height: 200px; width:300px; right: 0px;  background-color: green; bottom: 0;">
    ad
   </div>

   <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 200px; width:300px; right: 0px; top: 20px;  background-color: blue;">
    online
   </div>
   <div style="position: absolute; width:300px; right: 0px; top: 0px; height: 20px;  background-color: red;">
    online menu
   </div>
   <div style="position: absolute; right: 300px; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 20px;  background-color: yellow;">
    tabs
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your image link seems to be broken. Could you try Tinypic?

Comment: Allright, http://i52.tinypic.com/33m3g3o.png

Comment: Cool, that works, I'll update my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

Alright, a few questions were extracted from your question;

First off, a little tip: CSS in IE seems to be extremely different in most cases than other browsers. For this, use one of the various "IE Hack" symbols (I use the # symbol) in front of a property for it to only apply to IE.

For example:

```
html
{
   background: #F00 ;
   #background: #0F0 !important ;
}
```

will make all browsers show a red background, and only IE will have a green background.

Second, why not use the `min-width` and `min-height` properties? They are compatible with everything (and buggy in IE6 or earlier; check out [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/min-width#compatibilitysection) for more info) and always do the trick with me. Set the width and height (obviously) to 100%, and all of this on both html and body (like the following)

```
html, body {
   width: 100% ;
   height: 100% ;
   min-width: 900px ;
   min-height: 500px ;
}
```

As for other methods, you can try wrapping the *entire* page data (starting right *after* the body tag) with a div (making sure you leave it block) to have it span across the entire page.

Another note that's worthy of, well, noting, is that you should also apply an `overflow` property to the html/body as well if you want a clean full-screen site. Where you'll lose content if you go outside the window's width, it will remove any scrollbars *if you choose to get rid of them*.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

After looking at your new image link, this one is easy! :]

Keeping in mind that divs are block by default, the following should work (this is untested, so some tweaking may be necessary):

```
<body>
<div id="page">
    <div id="right">
        <div class="thirty">Top bar</div>
        <div class="tall">Middle bar</div>
        <div id="rt_bot">Bottom bar</div>
    </div>
    <div id="left">
        <div class="thirty">Left Top Bar</div>
        <div class="tall">Left Mid Bar</div>
        <div id="lf_bot">Left Bottom Bar</div>
    </div>
    <div id="container"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

and the CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100% ;
    height: 100% ;
    min-height: 500px ;
    min-width: 900px ;
    margin: 0px ;
}

div#page {
    height: 100% ;
}

div#right {
    float: right ;
    height: 100% ;
    width: 300px ;
}

div#rt_bot {
    height: 200px ;
}

div#left {
    float: left ;
}

.thirty {
    height: 30px ;
}

.tall {
    height: 100% ;
}

div#lf_bot {
    height: 50px ;
}
```

Comment: Hey, I know about min width/height and IE shitness, but that doesn't solve how to make the entire layout in CSS. I have tried so many things that I'm out of clues now. I can't get them all positioned in the right way... do you perhaps know how to make it?

Comment: One step ahead of you; I was editing this post in regards to your image. That should give you a good start. The idea is to break things up into as broad as sections and then work downward (how I did it was with the left and the right panes first, and then the rows in each.

Comment: I have tried your example, but it doesn't work at all =/ Thanks for the try tho but it is a really tricky layout :p Here is a picture http://i.imgur.com/eyDrL.png  If there only was something like width: 100% - 30px ;__;

Comment: Let me get home to a working environment and I'll work on this for you if there isn't another working answer!

Comment: Oke that would be really nice if you could do that :) Do you know when you'll be home?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an extremely complex question. I'm not entirely sure it's possible to do with purely CSS and no javascript/jQuery.

The way the box models are set up now just doesn't lend itself well to full width, full height layouts.

Comment: If you look at the edit I made at the first post it is possible, but IE screws it up, as usual =(

Comment: This is perfectly possible with pure CSS. This is exactly what CSS was created to do!

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I don't like using tables, but the auto height issue makes me turn to this...

Works with IE8, probably doesn't work on IE6, though... Nothing really works with IE6, so no worries.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <style type="text/css">

html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0; }
table#content {min-width: 900px; min-height: 500px; width: 100%; height: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; }
table#content td {border: 1px solid black; }
table#content td.topLeft {height: 30px; }
table#content td.topRight {width: 300px; height: 30px; }
table#content td.bottomLeft {height: 30px; }
table#content td.bottomRight {width: 300px; height: 200px; }
table#content tr.spacing {height: 170px; }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="content">
      <tr>
        <td class="topLeft">Top Left</td>
        <td class="topRight">Top Right</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="centerLeft" rowspan="2">Center Left</td>
        <td class="centerRight">Center Right</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="spacing">
        <td class="bottomRight" rowspan="2">Bottom Right</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="bottomLeft">Bottom Left</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tables are extremely unnecessary. I'm still on a business trip, but still monitoring this question. I'll be home sooner or later...

Comment: Tables are completely unnecessary. I was in a hurry when I wrote this.

Comment: Hey guys I'm sorry for the late reply. Was in prague and the internet decided to not work anymore. Back home now and I fixed it myself now! Thanks for all the help tho. I made it with a top div that has a relative position and a min-width/height. The div inside that div are placed with an absolute position and it works great in every browser! If you want you can see it in my new beta of my website: http://demontunes.com/v2.0/ (The entire website will get a major overhaul on friday so don't look at the gfx now :p)